# how can i redirect this urls in php htaccess file

Tags: php, .htaccess

i want to redirect this link https://company.com/company-shalmax-global-alliance-private-limited-u24299gj2018ptc104928/   with  https://company.com/company/shalmax-global-alliance-private-limited-u24299gj2018ptc104928/
 link for my website but when i use

```
Redirect http://company.com/company-waishni-care-private-limited-u24299dl2018ptc341326/ http://company.com/company/waishni-care-private-limited-u24299dl2018ptc341326 [QSA,L]
```

write in htaccess file

this link my site down and link is not working   .. how can i redirect this link..

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
header("Location:  https://company.com/company/shalmax-global-alliance-private-limited-u24299gj2018ptc104928/");
```

in the php file for the first link.

Comment: actually https://company.com/company-shalmax-global-alliance-private-limited-u24299gj2018ptc104928/  this is my old site url  and this page is not availbe right now.. that reason i can't use header() inside page...  i have to write code in .htaccess file..

Comment: @manoj_chauhan the page must be working for it to serve a .htaccess file to the client as well. I'm afraid you're out of luck

Answer (score 0):

If in .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^company\-shalmax\-global\-alliance\-private\-limited\-u24299gj2018ptc104928/$ https://company.com/company/shalmax-global-alliance-private-limited-u24299gj2018ptc104928/? [R=301,L]
```

or

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/company\-shalmax\-global\-alliance\-private\-limited\-u24299gj2018ptc104928/$ https://company.com/company/shalmax-global-alliance-private-limited-u24299gj2018ptc104928/
```